# Spring Data @Query with Joins

Tags: spring, join, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am fairly new to Spring Data and I want to create a query that will allow me to do an Inner Join between two entities.

I have been using this stack overflow to try to clarify certain aspects:

[How To Define a JPA Repository Query with a Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154818/how-to-define-a-jpa-repository-query-with-a-join)

It gives the answer of structuring the query as so:

```
@Query("select u.userName from User u inner join u.area ar where ar.idArea = :idArea")
```

However in this query I dont see where it manages to define "ar" as neither of the entity classes actually define "ar" within themselves? Any clarification on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tip: What does the `u` after User represent?

Comment: A user yes, but I was under the impression that the u was defined from "User u". In this query there is no "Area ar"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Define a JPA Repository Query with a Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154818/how-to-define-a-jpa-repository-query-with-a-join)

Answer (score 5):

Consider this example

```
SELECT c FROM Country c
```

Here, c is called a range variable.

> Range variables are query identification variables that iterate over
>   all the database objects of a specific entity class hierarchy (i.e. an
>   entity class and all its descendant entity classes)

You can read more about range variables [here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/from#Range_Variables_)

As per your query that *there is no "Area ar"* you need to understand that this query is based on JPQL (not SQL). Consider the below query:

```
SELECT c1, c2 FROM Country c1 INNER JOIN c1.neighbors c2
```

JPQL provides something called as a join variable, which represent a more limited iteration over specified collections of objects. In the above query, c1 is a range variable while c2 is a join variable that is bound to the path c1.neighbours and iterates only over objects in that collection.

You can read about it in more detail in [this article](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/from#INNER_JOIN_)

Answer (score 3):

area is actually defined in User entity class and in your query area is aliased with "ar" and used as second entity of the join.

```
@Query("select u.userName from User u inner join **u.area** ar
        where ar.idArea = :idArea")
```