# inner joins in spring boot jpa repositories

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, inner-join

I have three entities in my Spring Boot JPA project.

**A_Ent**

---

*| A_field1 |
 A_field2 |
 A_field3* |

---

**B_Ent**

---

*| B_field1 |
B_field2 |
B_field3* |

---

**C_Ent**

---

*| C_field1 |
C_field2 |
C_field3* |

---

I want to create queries with innerjoins in some of the repositories.

fx:

```
SELECT A_field1, B_field2 C_field3 FROM A_Ent AE
inner join B_Ent BE on (AE.field3 = BE.field3)
inner join C_Ent CE on (AE.field2 = CE.field2)
WHERE CE.field3 = 1
```

how can i add specific inner joins selects to my spring boot jpa repositories (if possible) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Define a JPA Repository Query with a Join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154818/how-to-define-a-jpa-repository-query-with-a-join)

Comment: clearly JPQL joins across relations, so without posting the entities and their relations, there is nothing to comment on

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use the old style of join in your JPQL query (i am assuming you have to join by non-primary/foreign keys):

```
select AE.A_field1, BE.B_field2 CE.C_field3 
from A_Ent AE, B_Ent BE, C_Ent CE 
where (AE.field3 = BE.field3)
   and (AE.field2 = CE.field2)
   and CE.field3 = 1
```

You have to remember that this will be a projection so you will get an `Object[]` or `List<Object[]>`, depending whether you use `uniqueResult()` or `list()` methods on the query respectively