# How to convert Select with Inner Join query in Spring Query

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, spring, spring-data-jpa

This is my SQL statement which works properly:

`SELECT cedula FROM paciente INNER JOIN titular ON paciente.id = titular.paciente_id WHERE cedula = '19163676';`

returns `cedula` field from `paciente` table when the ids match

I've read this post: [How To Define a JPA Repository Query with a Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154818/how-to-define-a-jpa-repository-query-with-a-join)

But in that post the relationship is One-to-One.

In my case, the relationship is Many-to-One where the father model is `paciente` and the child model is `titular`

This is my Paciente domain:

**Paciente.java**

```
@Id
@Column(name="pacienteId")
@SequenceGenerator(name="paciente_id_seq",
    sequenceName="paciente_id_seq",
    allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
    generator="paciente_id_seq")
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "cedula", nullable = false)
private String cedula;
```

And this is my Titular domain with the relationship:

**Titular.java**

```
 @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="pacienteId")
private Paciente paciente;
```

And this is my **PacienteRepository.java** which will contain the query:

```
public interface PacienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Paciente,Long> {
List<Paciente> findByNombreContainsIgnoreCase(String nombre);
List<Paciente> findByNombreLikeIgnoreCaseAndApellidoLikeIgnoreCase(String nombre, String apellido);
List<Paciente> findByCedula(String cedula);
Page<Paciente> findByCedulaStartsWith(String cedula, Pageable pageable);
```

}

How can I do it?

Comment: Try `SELECT DISTINCT...` if you are trying to only return 1 unique value.

Comment: The issue is related to Java/Spring and its query methods, in SQL works properly by this way.

Comment: What is your purpose for the JOIN?

Comment: Find only cedulas (ID cards) by paciente (patient) which match with Titular (account's owner)

Comment: What did you try? Did you get any error?

Comment: I tried this @Query: `@Query("select p.cedula from Paciente p inner join Titular.paciente_id_seq p where p.cedula = :cedula")
    Page<Paciente> findByCedulaEndsWith(@RequestParam("cedula") String cedula, Pageable pageable);`

Comment: But throws me the following error: `Error creating bean with name 'pacienteResource': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'pacienteRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pacienteRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.setech.segminedu.repository.PacienteRepository.findByCedulaEndsWith(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)!`

Comment: Why are you using `@ReqeustParam`? Use `@Param` from `Spring-Data-JPA`. `@RequestParam` applies to `Spring-MVC` to get request parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED (2017-07-06):**

JPQL isn't the same that SQL. JPQL can return the desired object through Entities (even, inside of a different Java repository Entity), no needs Inner Join command.

i.e.:

**PacienteRepository.java:**

```
@Query("select titular.paciente from Titular titular where titular.paciente.cedula in ?1")
Page<Paciente> findByCedulaEndsWith(String cedula, Pageable pageable);
```

That returns the patient from Titular table (owners), when its 'cedula' (ID card, DNI, etc) match with 'cedula' from Paciente (patients) table. Else, returns an empty array.