# Join using two different entities in spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have 2 different entities. table1 has a column which is primary key of table2.

both of the tables has respected repository.

If I write below query in one of the repository it gives error

> QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:

```
@Query("select new stats.UserCountDTO(b.objectiveId, count(b.objectiveId), a.locationCountry)"+ 
" from UserIdentityEntity a, UserObjectiveEntity b where b.userIdentityId == a.id and b.cId = ?1")
```

How can I write join queries in this case using spring data jpa?

Comment: this `b.userIdentityId == a.id` should be `b.userIdentityId = a.id`

Comment: oh yes.. silly mistake. had java conventions in mind. Thanks so much it works now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Define a JPA Repository Query with a Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154818/how-to-define-a-jpa-repository-query-with-a-join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just make a mistake. The

```
b.userIdentityId == a.id
```

should be:

```
b.userIdentityId = a.id
```