# How to run custom queries spring boot jpa controller

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm kinda new to Spring Boot and I'm trying to run a custom query here.
I have table Compras (sales) which basically stores the drugstore, the employee, value of the sale and timestamp of sale.

I've managed to list sales by the id of sales (idcompras) but that's not really what I want. I want to list what a specific employee bought and when, so the following query works just fine on SQL:

`select idfarmacia, idservidor, valorcompra, datacompra from compras where idservidor = idservidor;`

The above is the query I want to translate to spring boot. I must be doing something wrong that isn't obvious to me, so if anyone would point me in the right direction, I'm grateful.

Compras entity:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.NamedQuery;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "compras")
@NamedQuery(name = "Compras.findByIdServidor", query = "select c from Compras c where c.idservidor = ?1")
public class Compras {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idcompras")
    private Integer idcompras;
    
    @Column(name = "valorcompra")
    private double valorcompra;
    
    @Column(name = "datacompra")
    private Timestamp datacompra;
    
    @Column(name = "descricaoCompra")
    private String descricaoCompra;
   
    public String getDescricaoCompra() {
        return descricaoCompra;
    }

    public void setDescricaoCompra(String descricaoCompra) {
        this.descricaoCompra = descricaoCompra;
    }
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idservidor")
    private Servidor idservidor;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "iddependente")
    private Dependentes dependentes;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idfarmacia")
    private Farmacia farmacia;
    
    public Compras(){}

    public Servidor getServidor() {
        return idservidor;
    }

    public void setServidor(Servidor idservidor) {
        this.idservidor = idservidor;
    }

    public Dependentes getDependentes() {
        return dependentes;
    }

    public void setDependentes(Dependentes dependentes) {
        this.dependentes = dependentes;
    }

    public Farmacia getFarmacia() {
        return farmacia;
    }

    public void setFarmacia(Farmacia farmacia) {
        this.farmacia = farmacia;
    }

    public int getIdcompras() {
        return idcompras;
    }
    public void setIdcompras(int idcompras) {
        this.idcompras = idcompras;
    }
    public double getValorcompra() {
        return valorcompra;
    }
    public void setValorcompra(double valorcompra) {
        this.valorcompra = valorcompra;
    }
    public Timestamp getDatacompra() {
        return datacompra;
    }
    public void setDatacompra(Timestamp datacompra) {
        this.datacompra = datacompra;
    }
    public Compras(double valorcompra, Timestamp datacompra, String descricaoCompra) {
        this.valorcompra = valorcompra;
        this.datacompra = datacompra;
        this.descricaoCompra = descricaoCompra;
    }

}
```

Compras repository

```
package com.camaratapira.syspharma.repositories;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import com.camaratapira.syspharma.entity.Compras;

public interface ComprasRepository extends JpaRepository<Compras, Long>{

    List<Compras> findByidcompras(Integer idcompras);
    
    @Query("select c from Compras c where idservidor = :idservidor")
    List<Compras> findByIdServidor(@Param("idservidor") Integer idservidor);
}
```

Compras controller:

```
package com.camaratapira.syspharma.controller;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.camaratapira.syspharma.entity.Compras;

import com.camaratapira.syspharma.repositories.ComprasRepository;
import com.camaratapira.syspharma.repositories.FarmaciaRepository;
import com.camaratapira.syspharma.repositories.ServidorRepository;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ComprasController {

    @Autowired
    ComprasRepository comprasRepository;
    @Autowired
    ServidorRepository servidorRepository;
    @Autowired
    FarmaciaRepository farmaciaRepository;

    @GetMapping("/compras/listartodos")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Compras>> getAllCompras(@RequestParam(required=false) Integer idcompras){
        List<Compras> compras = new ArrayList<Compras>();       
        try {
                comprasRepository.findAll().forEach(compras::add);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(compras, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(compras, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            
        }
    }
    
    // TODO the results are not being cast correctly. Put the results into some sort of list.
    
    @GetMapping("/compras/listarcompras/{idservidor}")
    public ResponseEntity<Compras> getcomprasById(@PathVariable Integer idservidor){
        List<Compras> comprasData = comprasRepository.findByidservidor(idservidor);
        return new ResponseEntity<Compras>(comprasData.get(idservidor), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    // TODO listar compras por servidor
    // TODO inserir compras e deletar compras
    
    @PostMapping("/compras/realizarcompra")
    public ResponseEntity<Compras> createCompras(@RequestBody Compras compras){
        try {
            Compras _compras = comprasRepository.save(compras);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(_compras, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ResponseEntity<Compras>(null, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        
    }
    

}
```

When I try to pass a json request, spring complains that

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument [320] of type [java.lang.Integer] did not match parameter type [com.camaratapira.syspharma.entity.Servidor (n/a)]

**Edit: Servidor entity and stack trace:**

```
package com.camaratapira.syspharma.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "servidor")
public class Servidor {
    
    public Servidor(){}
    
    public Servidor(String nomeservidor, String cpf, String rg, double salario, boolean ativo) {
        super();
        this.nomeservidor = nomeservidor;
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.rg = rg;
        this.salario = salario;
        this.ativo = ativo;
    }
    

    
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "idfuncao")
    private Funcao funcao; // necessário fazer os métodos getters e setters dessas funções para poderem retornar as 
    // chaves estrangeiras quando você fizer uma requisição GET, caso contrário, o sistema não vai saber onde procurar.
        
    public Funcao getFuncao() {
        return funcao;
    }

    public void setFuncao(Funcao funcao) {
        this.funcao = funcao;
    }

    public int getIdservidor() {
        return idservidor;
    }
    public void setIdservidor(Integer idservidor) {
        this.idservidor = idservidor;
    }
    public String getNomeservidor() {
        return nomeservidor;
    }
    public void setNomeservidor(String nomeservidor) {
        this.nomeservidor = nomeservidor;
    }
    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }
    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }
    public String getRg() {
        return rg;
    }
    public void setRg(String rg) {
        this.rg = rg;
    }
    public double getSalario() {
        return salario;
    }
    public void setSalario(double salario) {
        this.salario = salario;
    }
    public boolean isAtivo() {
        return ativo;
    }
    public void setAtivo(boolean ativo) {
        this.ativo = ativo;
    }
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "idservidor")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) // outras estratégias precisam de tabelas específicas no Banco de dados
    private Integer idservidor;
    
    @Column(name = "nomeservidor")
    private String nomeservidor;
    
    @Column(name = "cpf")
    private String cpf;
    
    @Column(name = "rg")
    private String rg;
    
    @Column(name = "salario")
    private double salario;
    
    @Column(name = "ativo")
    private boolean ativo;
    

    
}
```

Stack trace:

```
2023-02-22T15:57:25.381-03:00[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Argument [320] of type [java.lang.Integer] did not match parameter type [com.camaratapira.syspharma.entity.Servidor (n/a)]] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument [320] of type [java.lang.Integer] did not match parameter type [com.camaratapira.syspharma.entity.Servidor (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:31) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.validate(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:339) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractCommonQueryContract.setParameter(AbstractCommonQueryContract.java:860) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.setParameter(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:708) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.setParameter(QuerySqmImpl.java:1263) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.setParameter(QuerySqmImpl.java:131) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$BindableQuery.setParameter(QueryParameterSetter.java:329) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$NamedOrIndexedQueryParameterSetter.lambda$setParameter$4(QueryParameterSetter.java:120) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$ErrorHandling$1.execute(QueryParameterSetter.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$NamedOrIndexedQueryParameterSetter.setParameter(QueryParameterSetter.java:120) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:83) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:75) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:97) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java:107) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:234) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:127) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:148) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:134) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy115.findByIdServidor(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.camaratapira.syspharma.controller.ComprasController.getcomprasById(ComprasController.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Please share your Servidor entity with us. You must change your query, it is not correct. You can inspire that query to fix it. **@Query("select c from Compras c INNER JOIN c.idservidor s where s.id= :idservidor")** . And you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13155018/8909313)

Comment: Not sure on which line you are getting this error, please share details along with the stack trace.

Comment: Edited to add Servidor entity and error messages

Comment: Try changing findByidcompras to findByIdcompras - JPA has rules.

Comment: Solved it by creating a custom method on the repository class: List<Compras> findAllByIdservidor(final Servidor servidor);